# Injecting NamedOptions across the assemblies in an asp.net core project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have configured a `NamedOption` in `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs` like following:

```
services.Configure<MyOpts>("myOpts", 
   opts => configuration.Bind("myOpts", opts));
```

I have a controller action in `asp.net core` api like following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert(CreateUserCommand command)
{
    var id = await Mediator.Send(command);

    return Ok(id);
}
```

This is my `CreateUserCommand`:

```
public class CreateUserCommand
{
    private MyOpts opts { get; }

    public CreateUserCommand(IOptionsSnapshot<MyOpts> opts)
    {
        this.opts = opts.Get("myOpts");
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

When client hits my api, I want `MyOpts` object injected in `CreateUserCommand(IOptionsSnapshot<MyOpts> opts)`. CreateUserCommand is in the assembly other than asp.net core project. Is it possible to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register also Commands in DI then yes (You usually don't register commands with DI), but based what I see CreateUserCommand is a payload (in your case) so I assume that you don't register it and it will not work (not only in a different assemblies but also in same assemblies).
Because you use Mediator I assume that you have a handler for CreateUserCommand and I think there you can inject your configuration and it will work.

Comment: Exactly. You are right. I'm using Mediator pattern and yes I injected it in the handler class. Worked like a charm! 
T

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Default ASP.NET Core DI supports the Injection across the multiple assemblies when done right.

Please refer the nice article for more details.

https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/03/06/using-dependency-injection-in-multiple-projects.html

Hope this helps!